# How does one reset an index attribute at the start of iterating over a custom iterator class in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So you know how when you iterate over a built-in iterable like, say, a `list`, in Python, the index starts at 0 every time:

```py
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for item in my_list:
    print(item)

for other_item in my_list:
    print(item)
```

Prints `1` through `5` twice. I.e. when `my_list` is iterated over again it starts from the beginning of the list again, not from `5`.

I implemented my own custom iterator class structured like this (minimal abstracted example, with only the structures relevant to iteration):

```py
class MyIterator:
    def __init__(self, my_list: list):
         self.my_list = my_list
         self._iteration_index = 0

    def __iter__(self):
         return self

    def __next__(self):
         element = self.my_list[self._iteration_index]
         self._iteration_index += 1
         
         if self._iteration_index >= len(self.my_list) - 1:
             raise StopIteration
         
         return element
```

Currently, if I create an object of type `MyIterator`, I can only iterate over it once. Is there somewhere I can set `self._iteration_index` back to `0` so that each time I iterate over it, it starts from the beginning of `self.my_list`?

I am using Python 3.11.7

Comment: `list` itself is *not* an iterator, though. `iter([1,2,3])` doesn't return `[1,2,3]`, but a `list_iterator` object that *wraps* `[1,2,3]`. It's the `list_iterator` object that tracks the current position, independently of any *other* `list_iterator`s that might wrap the same list.

Comment: "I can only iterate over it once." Yes, that's somewhat the point. While you could expose a way to "rewind" the iterator, that's not something the iterator protocol guarantees will be available. Further, it is [explicitly documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator.__next__) that an iterator that raises `StopIteration` once must *always* raise `StopIteration` thereafter. You can't "unstop" an iterator.

Comment: There is a [difference between an iterable and an iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884132/what-are-iterator-iterable-and-iteration).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterators are not permitted to reset [in the way you want](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator.__next__):

> Once an iterator’s `__next__()` method raises StopIteration, it must continue to do so on subsequent calls. Implementations that do not obey this property are deemed broken.

If you want to iterate over your object twice, you need to use two separate iterators.

Use two separate class. One represents your iterable; the other the iteration *over* that iterable.

```
class MyIterable:
    def __init__(self, my_list: list):
        self.my_list = list

    def __iter__(self):
        return MyIterator(self)


class MyIterator:
    def __init__(self, iterable):
        self.list = iterable.list
        self.index = 0
        self.stopped = False

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.stopped:
            raise StopIteration

        try:
            x = self.list[self.index]
        except IndexError:
            self.stopped = True
            raise StopIteration

        self.index += 1
        return x
```

This is not necessarily the best implementation of `MyIterator`, but it demonstrates two things:

1. The iterator tracks the current index independently of the thing you are iterating over. You can have multiple simultaneous iterators for the same object.

   ```
   x = MyIterable([1,2,3])
   i1 = MyIterator(x)
   i2 = MyIterator(x)
   assert next(i1) == 1
   assert next(i2) == 1
   assert next(i1) == 2
   ```
2. Proper iterators must never produce a value once it has raised `StopIteration`. The `stopped` flag ensures that, even if the underlying list is modified after a previous attempt to get a value. (Modifying the underlying list *before* the iterator has raised `StopIteration` is a problem as well, which is why the standard advice is to never modify the thing you are iterating over.)

---

Rather than implementing the iterator class yourself, though, you can make `__iter__` a generator function, so that every time it is called it produces a *new* generator that will iterate over whatever you like.

```
class MyIterable:
    def __init__(self, my_list: list):
        self.my_list = list

    def __iter__(self):
        yield from self.my_list
```

Comment: Thank you, this was very comprehensive and helpful!

Answer (score -1):

I think this solution can help you

```
class MyIterator:
    def __init__(self, my_list: list):
        self.my_list = my_list
        self._iteration_index = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self._iteration_index >= len(self.my_list):
            self._iteration_index = 0
            raise StopIteration
        element = self.my_list[self._iteration_index]
        self._iteration_index += 1
        return element
```

Comment: If you append to the list, this `__next__` can produce a value after the first time you raise `StopIteration`, which violates the iterator protocol.

Comment: (Even if you don't, reseting the index to 0 allows that, too.)

Comment: I understand protocol of Iterator, but question was not about how works Iterator, but how ```back to 0 so that each time I iterate over it, it starts from the beginning of self.my_list```   If catch StopIteration, my solution get answer on question)))

Comment: I don't think you do: the iterator protocol *explicitly* disallows going back to 0 to restart the iteration.

Comment: You can observe this with the built-in `list`: `x = [1]; i = iter(x); next(1); next(i); x.append(2); next(i)`. The last call to `next` still raises `StopIteration`, even though another value has been added to the list.

Comment: I got you and I am agree with you about iterator protocol. I just wanted to gieve a solution that person. At least you are right without any doubt.